# React Native: Google OAuth Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, expo

I have some problems with authentication with Google OAuth2 in my react-native app. I'm using 'expo-auth-session' library for my authentification. I need get access token and then get Youtube profile. But i'm stuck with error "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Invalid scheme"

My scheme in app.json:

```
"scheme": "com.liga.online"
```

My code is below:

```
import {
  makeRedirectUri,
  useAuthRequest,
  ResponseType,

} from "expo-auth-session";

const discoveryYoutube = {
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    revocationEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke'
};


/// Inside my React component
const [requestYoutube, responseYoutube, promptAsyncYoutube] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType: ResponseType.Code,
      clientId: YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"],
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        native: "com.liga.online/callback",
      }),
    },
    discoveryYoutube
  );
```

When I press the button, callback is starting

```
  const signInYoutube = async () => {
    const response = await promptAsyncYoutube();
    console.log(response.data);
  }
```

But I get error[image]

Any idea how I can fix it?

P.S. I tried fix it with library "expo-google-app-auth". I get access token, but when I try to get Youtube profile and get "Request failed with status code 403".

**UPDATE 1**

By the way about my connection to Youtube Profile.

I change something to get access token.

For example:

```
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
import { startAsync } from 'expo-auth-session';


// Inside my React component

// When I press the button, callback is starting

const signInYoutube = async () => {

    const config = {
        androidClientId: YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID
    };

    const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync(config);


    // I need again open my Browser for get Youtube data
    const response = await startAsync({
            authUrl: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?access_token=${accessToken}&part=snippet&mine=true&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`,
            showInRecents: true
    });

    console.log(response.data);
}
```

But I get error

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I wanted to see which data is loaded from AuthRequest. And I see pretty weird log. Redirect_uri is different from the set.[image]

**RESOLUTION**

When I add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly" in my scopes - i can get profile data. Another words below is my code.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';

// Inside my React component

// Callback function

const signInYoutube = async () => {
    const config = {
        androidClientId: YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
    };

    const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync(config);

    if (type === 'success') {
        const response = await axios.get(
                    `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&key=${encodeURI(YOUTUBE_API_KEY)}`,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                        }
                    }
                );

        setYoutubeData({ accessToken, user, youtubeId: response.data.items[0].id });
    }
};
```

**IMPORTANT**

Don't remember add in [your project](https://console.developers.google.com/) [Youtube API v3](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com?q=YoutubeData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your expo environment is using the development redirect URI instead of the native one. Check out these docs for setting up the environment that will give you the native scheme you're looking for: https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#standalone-bare-or-custom

Also make sure that you register your custom scheme with Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_custom-scheme

As for your Youtube example, you should be specifying the `scopes` in the call to `Google.loginAsync`, not the call to the Youtube API. `scopes` are requested during the authorization step, and your current authorization request doesn't include any. The relevant docs are here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/#loginasync

Comment: Yeah, you was absolutelly correct about:

> As for your Youtube example, you should be specifying the scopes in the call to Google.loginAsync, not the call to the Youtube API. scopes are requested during the authorization step, and your current authorization request doesn't include any.

I add in the array of scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly" and get youtube profile data. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**REDIRECT URI**

Your code looks roughly right though your redirect URI is a private URI scheme and should include a colon character:

- com.liga.online:/callback

**TRACING MESSAGES**

For people to help you with your YouTube profile request you'll need to be able to tell us what is being sent over HTTP/S. Could you try to trace messages as in [this write up of mine](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging/), then paste the request and response details into your question above